# calculate different between a column of a table in two days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below in oracle database:

```
s_num     eff_date     amount
1         07-OCT-18      110
1         06-OCT-18      50
2         07-OCT-18      200
2         06-OCT-18      150
```

I want to find the different between "amount" column for today and yesterday. and the result must be like below

```
s_num    diff
1         60
2         50
```

I want to do this without join the table with itself.

Comment: Without joining the table with itself, it'll be a little hard (maybe using analytical functions).

Comment: It can be solved creating a function and using DEFAULT keyword.Check out my answer below..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT s_num,SUM (CASE 
                    WHEN eff_date >= TRUNC(sysdate) 
                       AND eff_date < TRUNC(sysdate) + 1 THEN amount --today
                    WHEN eff_date >= TRUNC(sysdate) - 1 
                       AND eff_date < TRUNC(sysdate) THEN - amount --yesterday
                END) 
    FROM   t 
    GROUP  BY s_num;
```

Or `LAG` function

```
SELECT s_num, 
       diff 
FROM   (SELECT s_num, 
               eff_date,
               amount - LAG(amount, 1, 0) 
                          OVER ( 
                            partition BY s_num 
                            ORDER BY eff_date ) AS diff 
        FROM   t) 
WHERE  eff_date >= trunc(sysdate) 
       AND eff_date < trunc(sysdate) + 1 ;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a234f1357d41c1dc247e8931f5cee243)

The first one will print `NULL` difference for days other than today, the second one does not return any rows for other dates.

Comment: No overheads dude..Simply can be done by using DEFAULT and user defined function..

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala : What overhead you are talking about? How is using your user defined function more performant? Have you run an `EXPLAIN PLAN`? What if there are multiple rows for a given date, does it work? How about if I run the query using your  function tomorrow, will it give the required  result?

Answer (score -1):

```
sql>set serveroutput on;
sql>create or replace function difference(n in number) return number as di 
    number(5);
 2  begin
 3  select ((select amount from oc where dob=trunc(sysdate) and snum=n)- 
    (select 
    amount from oc where dob=trunc(sysdate-1) and snum=n)) into di from dual;
 4  return di;
 5  end;
 6  /
 sql>select distinct snum,difference(snum) as diff from oc;
```

output:

```
                   SNUM       DIFF
            ---------- ----------
                    2         50
                    1         60
```

Comment: This will require two table/index scans for each call to the function and the function uses static dates so you cannot use it for any other day than today. Also, `'07-oct-18'` is not a date it is a string literal so you are relying on implicit conversion to a date and hoping that the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` matches (and if it doesn't then the query will break). All-in-all, don't use this method - just use the `LAG` analytic function.

Comment: @MT0 As per the user who asked i have coded this.Please read the line "difference between amount column for today and yesterday" in the query

Comment: @MT0 According to the query user has given the information about the internal data and where dob="07-oct-18",is the way we check right.I am using where clause (conditional clause).

Comment: But if you run the query tomorrow, it will not return the results for that date's "today" and "yesterday" it will always return it for static dates; so it will work today but it will not answer the OP's question tomorrow. Also, try running `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';` and run your function - it will not work even though the function has not changed.

Comment: as per the requirement i have edited to dynamic date